# ¿Cómo mostrar el contenido de un array tipo int en un TextView? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, array, textview

Tengo dos arrays tipo int estaticos por ahora, uno es mas largo que otro, mi objetivo es invertir el array mas corto y simplemente mostrarlo en un TextView.

Ejemplo: array1 = {1,2,3} y en TextView  saldrá = {3,2,1}

Traté de hacer el codigo de la siguiente manera pero solo me muestra un 0 en el TextView.

**Metodo:**

```
public void ArrayInvertido() {

    //probando con 2 array estaticos
    int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int array2[] = {2,2,2,2,2,2};

    if(array1.length<array2.length){ //entonces array1 sera el array invertido

        //el array invertido será del tamaño del array inicial mas largo
        int[] arrayinvertido = new int[array2.length];

        //invirtiendo el array
        for (int i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arrayinvertido[i] += array1[i];
        }

        //mostrando el array invertido
        for (int i=0;i< arrayinvertido.length;i++){
            txtreflex.setText("" + arrayinvertido[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Tengo esto en la clase Main.

**Clase Main:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private Button btn_mostrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_mostrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mostrar);
 
    btn_mostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayInvertido();

        }
    });
}


public void ArrayInvertido() { 
 ...
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba con este codigo:

```
//probando con 2 array estaticos
int[] array1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] array2 = {2,2,2,2,2,2};

if(array1.length<array2.length){ //entonces array1 sera el array invertido
    //el array invertido será del tamaño del array inicial mas largo
    int[] arrayinvertido = new int[array2.length];
    //invirtiendo el array
    for (int i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        arrayinvertido[array1.length-i-1] = array1[i];
    }
    //mostrando el array invertido
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for (int value : arrayinvertido) {
        sb.append(value);
    }
    txtreflex.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: perfecto, gracias por tu aporte, ahora si muestra el array invertido, anteriormente mostraba era una especie de l@345, como el espacio de memoria, y no los elementos. Gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

Debes inicializar la variable `txtreflex` de igual forma que lo haces con el `Button`, y la forma de invertir el array es incorrecta, de echo lo que hace es copiarlo igual.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como invertirlo que te puede servir:

```
for (int i = 0, j = array1.length - 1; i < arrayinvertido.length; i++, j--) {
    arrayinvertido[i] = array1[j];
}
```

Comment: gracias por el ajuste de la inversion pude corregirlo a como lo sugieres, pero aun tengo problema con la parte de mostrar, ya conecté la parte grafica con la parte logica txtreflex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_reflex); pero aun asi me sale error y se cierra el emulador

Comment: que error te da? guarda el texto a mostrar en una variable y haz el `txtreflex.setText()` fuera del bucle como te han sugerido