# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta el metodo que muestra un array en un TextView? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, array, string, parsear

Estoy haciendo una App en la que pide en dos EditText ingresar X numeros separados por comas y mostrará un array invertido (al revés) del EditText mas corto despues de haber sido ingresado.

Ejemplo: EditText={1,2,3,4,5} y lo que se muestra en el TextView = {5,4,3,2,1}

Hasta el momento todo esta bien con eso, el problema es que al ejecutar el codigo, la aplicacion abre normalmente pero al momento de presionar el boton se detiene la aplicacion.

**Este es el main:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText Tsignal1;
private EditText Tsignal2;
private TextView txtreflex;
private String  Ssignal1;
private String  Ssignal2;

private Button btn_mostrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Tsignal1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_param_s1);
    Tsignal2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_param_s1);
    btn_mostrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mostrar);
    txtreflex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_reflex);

    Ssignal1 = Tsignal1.getText().toString();
    Ssignal2 = Tsignal2.getText().toString();

    btn_mostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayInvertido();
        }
    });
}
```

**Este es el método** donde convierte el EditText a string y de string a array string separando las posiciones con un .split despues de cada coma, y posteriormente convirtiendo ese array string a un array int (para asi mas adelante poder operar matematicamente con las posiciones de los dos array)

```
public void ArrayInvertido() {

    // guardando posicion en array string por cada coma que encuentre
    String[] ArraySignal1 = Ssignal1.split(",");
    String[] ArraySignal2 = Ssignal2.split(",");

    //parseando de array tipo string a array tipo int
    int[] array1 = new int[ArraySignal1.length];
    for (int i=0; i < ArraySignal1.length; i++) {
        array1[i] = Integer.parseInt(ArraySignal1[i]);
    }

    int[] array2 = new int[ArraySignal2.length];
    for (int i=0; i < ArraySignal2.length; i++) {
        array2[i] = Integer.parseInt(ArraySignal2[i]);
    }

    //si array1 es menor entonces sera el array invertido
    if(array1.length<array2.length){
        int[] arrayinvertido = new int[array1.length];

        //invirtiendo el array
        for (int i=0, j=array1.length - 1; i<arrayinvertido.length; i++, j--) {
            arrayinvertido[i] = array1[j];
        }
        
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for (int value : arrayinvertido) {
            sb.append(value);
        }
        //mostrando el array invertido
        txtreflex.setText(sb.toString());

    }else{
        int[] arrayinvertido = new int[array2.length];

        //invirtiendo el array
        for (int i=0, j=array2.length - 1; i<arrayinvertido.length; i++, j--) {
            arrayinvertido[i] = array1[j];
        }
        
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for (int value : arrayinvertido) {
            sb.append(value);
        }
        
        //mostrando el array invertido
        txtreflex.setText(sb.toString());
    }
    
}
```

}

Habia incorporado varios try catch para encontrar mas exactamente donde estaba el problema que de hecho lo lanzaba en el metodo, y segun el debug, me la marca en la linea   `array1[i] = Integer.parseInt(ArraySignal1[i]);` de la parte del parseo de array string a array int

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mostrá el error que sale en el logcat

Comment: Pueden ser varias las causas , lo mejor es revisar el LogCat , cual es el mensaje que se registra al cerrarse la app?

Comment: Esta pregunta ya la habìas realizado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368613/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-el-contenido-de-un-array-tipo-int-en-un-textview-android-studio